Docx4j convert HTML with two or more CSS classes
I see that in my HTML to Docx code, I can only use ONE CSS class per p tag? How can I have attributes of two or more CSS applied.
Sample HTML code
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .txcenter {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .txred {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="txred txcenter">My Text</p>
</body>
</html>

Then only the txred class applied. The word "My Text" turn red in Word document, but not align center. And if I define class txcenter before txred, "My Text" is aligned center in Word but the color stays black.
This is my Java code, variable htmlContent is the HTML string:
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
    wordPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addAltChunk(AltChunkType.Xhtml, htmlContent.getBytes());
    wordPackage.save(new File(MY_FILE_PATH));


If you merely add an altChunk like that, you are relying on Word to convert it to docx content on opening (which it apparently does badly in this case).
docx4j-ImportXHTML can convert it for you, if you add that to your classpath and invoke wordPackage.getMainDocumentPart().convertAltChunks()
